# Dependency injection factory based on text file

Tags: python, dependency-injection, factory

I would like to create some objects hierarchy in Python based on a text file (yml, json whatever). I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel. But maybe I don't know how to google it or there is no such a framework.

Let me give a simple pseudo example of what I'm looking for:

Let's assume I have the following classes:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, b):
        pass

class B:
    def __init__(self, number):
        pass
```

I would like to create a text file like this:

```
object_a:
    factory: A
    b: object_b

object_b:
    factory: B
    number: 12
```

and pass it to some builder/factory to automatically build objects with their dependencies.

Comment: I'd be rather surprised if such a thing existed. Most serialization formats actively *avoid* giving the data any control about the deserialization process. Just imagine if someone sent you a file that read `factory: eval, code: os.remove('/')`...

Comment: Understand it - it cannot be given to everyone or run in unprotected environment. It's clear. Still can be usefull for "internal" usage.